# SQLite GROUP BY week of rows having date

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite3 with columns of `[email, date]`.

I’d like to count the number of rows in each week, so essentially I think I need a `GROUP BY` week `SELECT` statement.

I’ve been looking around for examples online, some of them mentioning the use of `DATEPART`, but SQLite doesn’t seem to offer that.

I could get the rows into PHP and try to group them from there, but I feel this should be possible to do in SQL.

Comment: you haven't accepted answers for any question asked for the last year.

Comment: @sixfeetsix I went in and fixed that, for some reason I forgot to accept some answers - thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite use **strftime** as an alternative to compute times, in strftime the appropriate function to get the number of the week is:
**%W** which is replaced by the week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 00. according to strftime [docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).

So yo can try something like:

```
SELECT
    strftime('%W',date_column) AS WeekNumber,
    column1,
    column2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY WeekNumber;
```

This should give you a new column withe the week number and the columns you want to group by, hope it helps.

Comment: If your data spans multiple years, you should add year to the `strfitme` or else it will combine the data from different years.